# Integrar correctamente una aplicación python en Apache con mod_wsgi

Tags: python, apache, flask

He creado un host virtual para integrar en Apache una api REST escrita en `python` utilizando el framework `Flask`. Ahora bien, este es el código de mi `__init__.py`:

```
from flask import Flask
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy    
from controler import Controler

def get_credentials():

    import json
    with open('credentials.json') as json_data:#lectura de credenciales bbdd

        credentials = json.load(json_data)

   return credentials


cr = get_credentials()  
app = Flask(__name__)    
app.config['SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI'] = 'mysql+pymysql://' + cr['dbuser'] + ':' + cr['dbpassword'] + '@'+ cr['host'] + ':' + cr['port'] + '/' + cr['dbname']    
app.config['SQLALCHEMY_TRACK_MODIFICATIONS'] = False
print "Hello!!"
db = SQLAlchemy(app)
ctr = Controler()

@app.route("/api")
def hello():

    return "Hello, it's working!"

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run()
```

Gracias a ese `print "Hello!!"` y revisando los `logs` de Apache, he visto que cada vez que hago un `GET` a la ruta `http://localhost/api` no ejecuta únicamente el código asignado a esa URI (función `hello`), sino que ejecuta nuevamente todo el código del fichero, incluyendo la lectura de las credenciales, la creación de la aplicación, la conexión con la base de datos y la generación del Controlador.

¿Cómo puedo hacer para que la parte inicial del fichero se ejecute una sola vez (cuando se inicie Apache) y se utilicen sus resultados posteriormente en las peticiones `GET` o `POST` que haga a la api en lugar de ejecutarse el fichero entero cada vez? Así era como funcionaba antes de integrar la aplicación `Flask` en Apache y me gustaría mentener el funcionamiento.